# Can anyone recommend resources for clusterwise-linear mixed analysis (preferably with R implementation)?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, clustering

I mean, something like clusterwise-regression, but accounting for the random effects as well…?

Explanation to the question:
I am trying to predict aesthetic ratings from the acoustics of melodies (so the experiment was: I asked participants how much they liked melody excerpts on a 7-point scale). I ran a linear mixed effects analysis (`lme4` package in R) with acoustic features as fixed effects and subjects and items (melody stimuli) as random effects with random intercepts. Turns out that the acoustic features could hardly predict a small part of the variance of ratings (marginal $R^2 = 0.015$, conditional $R^2 = 0.461$, `MuMIn` package in R).

I was surprised by this since when I look at mean ratings, I do find moderate correlations with some of the acoustic features. So just to explore it a bit further I tried fitting individual multiple regression models (that is, subsetting data to just one participant at a time; I know there are dependency issues here, I just wanted to understand the data). With this approach I got adjusted $R^2$ ranging from near zero to 0.6, with different subsets of predictors depending on the participant.

Now I guess I could do this for all 300 participants and then try to group them “by hand” (or do some cluster analysis of that result), and then model each group separately, but there probably is a better way…!? Some kind of clusterwise linear mixed analysis that clusters participants together according to how much their ratings can be explained by the same acoustic predictors.

I found some things on clusterwise regression, but I don’t see how that would work in this case, since I need to maintain each participant as one “minimal, individual cluster”, without collapsing all observations together.
Any help will be much appreciated!

**EDIT** (too long for a comment):

Working with aesthetic preferences, I am interested in the inter-individual differences here, so the random effects output is of course important.

But I suspect there are “profiles” of subjects whose preferences (or “liking” ratings) are more influenced by some acoustic features of the melodies than others (say, some pay more attention to vibrato in the voice, others to pitch accuracy, tempo etc, maybe with complex interactions, though I didn’t even try to model those yet; and some are really not that influenced by the acoustics and are responding based on their mood, associations they have with those stimuli etc).

This would explain why I get low R2 values when modelling all subjects together, even if I just use multiple regression (the fixed effects results are the same) but higher R2 values for some individual data (provided this inference is still valid, since I only have 32 trials per subject and there are dependency issues with regression here; and I reckon interpretation of R2 values in LMM is controversial).

So back to the question: how can I identify such subgroups of subjects with the same profile of relationship between ratings and acoustic predictors with a linear mixed analysis?

Comment: From the description, a regular mixed effects model should be fine for this. I wouldn't pay too  much attention to  $R^2$ for mixed models.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the question because my comment here was too long. But summarising, I would like to ask you to please elaborate on how I could find the best “grouping” of participants with a regular mixed effects model (please see edit above)

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean. I think you may want to use a latent class mixed effects approach.

Comment: I'm reading about latent class mixed models and they seems promising. Thank you!